# How to interpret hand written will that refers to children and possibly in-laws?

Tags: surnames, palaeography, pennsylvania, will

I'm looking at the March 8, 1869 will of Samuel Fought in Monroe, Cumberland, Pennsylvania shown here:

[image]

I'm having trouble reading the names of his children.  As best as I can tell it reads something like the following transcription starting at the last line of the left page and continuing to the top of the right page:

> ... divided between my children *Lry* Martha *Entermarried* with Henry *Rheinhart* Meg Son John Elizabeth *Entermarried* with William Stevenson Henry B. Fought Isaac S. Fought William E. Fought Jonathan E Fought Mary Jane Fought share and share alike ... and so my son John is *now* dead and has left a daughter Ann Virginia Fought his share to go to his said daughter ... and I hereby charge my son John Fought now deceased with three hundred dollars and my daughter Martha Seventy five dollars and my daughter Elizabeth with Fifty dollars and my son Henry B Fought with seven hundred dollars and my son Isaac S Fought with seventy five dollars and my son William E Fought with five hundred dollars and further it is my desire that should my granddaughter Ann Virginia die before arriving at the age of twenty one years that all the money belonging to his in the hands of her guardian which come to her from her father, my John, should in that event divest to the rest of my children or their legal issue and further a bureau, a bed, and a looking glass is reserved for my daughter Mary Jane she having got the same as a present from her grand father Eckels and further I hereby nominate constitute and appoint my son Isaac S Fought my executor of this my last will and testament — In witness whereof I Samuel Fought the testator have to this my last will written on one sheet of paper and set my hand and seal this eight day of March one thousand eight hundred and sixty nine.

Is the word really *Entermarried* and does that mean he is naming his children's spouses?  Also what is the word *lry* and is the name *Rheinhart*?  Is it really stating that John is already dead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ... divided between my children **viz** Martha Entermarried with Henry
>   **Rhinehart**, **My** Son John, Elizabeth Entermarried with William
>   Stevenson, Henry B. Fought, Isaac S. Fought, William E. Fought, Jonathan E.
>   Fought, Mary Jane Fought share and share alike ... and **as** my son John
>   is now dead and has left a daughter Ann Virginia Fought his share to
>   go to his said daughter ... and I hereby charge my son John Fought now
>   deceased with three hundred dollars and my daughter Martha Seventy
>   five dollars and my daughter Elizabeth with Fifty dollars and my son
>   Henry B Fought with seven hundred dollars and my son Isaac S Fought
>   with **Twenty** five dollars and my son William E Fought with five
>   hundred dollars and further it is my desire that should my
>   granddaughter Ann Virginia die before arriving at the age of twenty
>   one years that all the money belonging to **her** in the hands of her
>   guardian which came to her from her father, my John, should in
>   that event **revert** to the rest of my children or their legal issue
>   and further a bureau, a bed, and looking glass is reserved for my
>   daughter Mary Jane she having got the same as a present from her grand
>   father Eckels and further I hereby nominate constitute and appoint my
>   son Isaac S Fought my executor of this my last will and testament — In
>   witness whereof I Samuel Fought the testator have to this my last will
>   written on one sheet of paper and set my hand and seal this eight day
>   of March one thousand eight hundred and sixty nine.

- *viz.* is the abbreviation of the Latin adverb *videlicet*, meaning "namely" or "that is to say".
- *Entermarried* simply means "married with". It is more commonly spelled intermarried. Yes, the testator is naming his daughter's husbands. I have added punctuation to that part of my transcription above which is not present in the original, in the hope it makes it clearer.
- My impression is that the surname of the son-in-law is Henry
  Rhinehart, although it is a little bit difficult to differentiate
  whether it is "ine" vs "ein". In either case, it's a variant spelling
  of the same name.
- Yes, his son John is already dead by the time the will was written.

Comment: Do you think that John and Jonathan E are two different people?

Comment: @WilliamKF Yes, almost certainly.